# Accessing manually rendered form fields from Jquery

Tags: python, jquery, html, django

When I render a form normally my code will validate the image file and send it through. If I manually render the form fields the validation falls.

**Normal Form**:

```
{{ form }}
```

**Manually rendered fields**:

```
<div class="form-row">
    {{ form.username }}
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    {{ form.image }}
</div>
```

**Jquery handling the image**:

```
      $("#id_image").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            console.log(this.files[0]);
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#image").attr("src", e.target.result);
            $("#modalCrop").modal("show");
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
```

I have tried to change `this.files[0]` to `this.files[6]` since the image is the 7th item in the form but that did not work. Help?

Comment: Is #id_image input type="file"?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. When the form is built by Django the form is `input type=file`, yes.

Comment: $("#id_image").change(), do you listen the change of type="file" input? Also if you don't have such input, how are you going to upload?

Comment: This is all manually rendered by Django. You dont have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get files from event instance

```
$("#id_image").change(function (e) {
    let files = e.target.files
    ...
});
```